# F#: arithmetic operator and loss of polymorphism (value restriction?)

Tags: f#, parametric-polymorphism, value-restriction, adhoc-polymorphism

This code doesn't compile:

```
let f = fun x y -> x <<< y // bit shift
let g = fun x y -> x <<< y

[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =
  printfn "%d" <| f 1 10
  printfn "%d" <| f 1L 10 // error
  printfn "%d" <| g 1L 10
  0
```

```
(7,21): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    int
but here has type
    int64
```

- http://ideone.com/qktsOb

I guess the unifier fixed the type parameters associated with `f` and `g` upon seeing their first occurrences.  What governs this process?  I think this is very similar to "value restriction" but `f` and `g` are already eta-expanded!  This is a hard problem.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_restriction

I would surely imagine there's some black magic behind typing predefined operators with ad-hoc polymorphism over integral types, but that's just my speculation.  Any information appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic numeric programming is done using static member constraints, which can't be represented in the .NET type system. They exist only in F# and therefore must be marked `inline`.

Your code could be written this way:

```
let inline f x y = x <<< y // bit shift
let inline g z y = z <<< y

[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =
  printfn "%d" <| f 1 10
  printfn "%d" <| f 1L 10 // works too
  printfn "%d" <| g 1L 10
  0
```

More info on MSDN:
[Inline Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548047.aspx)
[Statically Resolved Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548046.aspx)

Comment: I wonder how long it could have took me to find these pages by myself!

Comment: I would like to expand on this answer, which has actually two parts: 1) Defining a syntactic function instead of a right-hand-side lambda function solves the value restriction problem: `let f x y = x <<< y`, and 2) the `inline` solves the operator constraint problem. B.t.w., `System.Int32` does not really have a static member `op_LeftShift`. The F# compiler implicitly augments the type with it, which further complicates type inference.

Comment: @MarcSigrist I think `let f x y = x <<< y` is just a syntax sugar for `let f = fun x y -> x <<< y`.  I was just desperate in getting my code compile, so I used the most verbose form trying to get any possible clues.  It should be compared against the partial application form `let f = (<<<)` and this one should be vulnerable to value restriction.

Comment: @nodakai: There is a meaningful distinction in F# between _syntactic functions_ and _function values_. Only syntactic functions can be inlined.

Comment: @Daniel Could you point me towards some in-depth explanation of the difference between syntactic functions and function values?

Comment: I would probably start with [_Automatic Generalization_](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233183.aspx) (especially the section on value restriction) on MSDN. This [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mulambda/archive/2010/05/01/value-restriction-in-f.aspx) on "the finer points" is also very good. The essence of F#'s behavior is captured by this sentence in the first article: _The compiler performs automatic generalization only on complete function definitions that have explicit arguments, and on simple immutable values._

Answer (score 1):

I think it is how F# performs automatic generalization of function parameters. On first appearance it infers that the function 'f' could have type ('a -> 'a -> 'a) but the second appearance is not match this signature because it has a different signature ('b -> 'a -> 'a) because it consider int64 and int as different types.

Inlining functions could sometimes solve this problem as @Daniel mentioned

Slightly more info could be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233183.aspx

Some more info on static member constraints could be found in this post by Tomas Petricek:
http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-generic-numeric.aspx/

Comment: "On first appearance it infers that the function `f` could have type `('a -> 'a -> 'a)`"  I don't think that is how HM works.  HM infers the most general type of a function (a term, in general) just by looking at its definition (body.)  (In this case `^a -> int32 -> ^a when ...`)

Comment: Note the difference between my problem and `max 2.0 3` in the MSDN page you quoted.  My `f` and `g` are essentially identical, so when the first and the third line of the body of my `main` function compile fine, there shouldn't be any reason for the second line not to compile (unless... complications like "static method" are involved.)  OTOH the problem with `max 2.0 3` is simply that the definition of `max` itself was not general enough to support such a usage.

Comment: I'll make time to read through Tomas' article.  Thank you very much for the valuable information!